# Android studio gives me an error when I try to add the Google Play Services Maps function

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been having a lot of issue with my dependencies on this project. I was trying to add Google Maps to my app, but when I do I receive this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. 
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from 
AndroidManifest.xml:16:13-35 is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-16:38 to override.
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.leoconnelly.connexus"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    //buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

//Helpshift
// use version 26.1.0 instead of 26.0.2
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'

implementation('com.helpshift:android-helpshift-en-aar:6.4.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'design'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview'
    exclude module: 'cardview-v7'

}


implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
}
```

and here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
package="com.example.leoconnelly.connexus">
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HealthCenterListActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".HealthCenterSelectedActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MoreInfoActivity" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.0.1" />

</application>
```

This issue only occurs when google play services are added. This is difficult because when I added helpshift yesterday, I had to change a lot of dependencies. Any advice on how to get this to work?

Comment: can you post your manifest? at least the beginning of it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `exclude module:support-v4` to helpshift and add support-v4 library to override another support library:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'

implementation('com.helpshift:android-helpshift-en-aar:6.4.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'design'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview'
    exclude module: 'cardview-v7'
    exclude module:support-v4
}
```